# Send an enum to graphql API from react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have an input (attached image) that I need to send to the graphql api from react application.

[image]

I am using below code to send this object and enum with init to graphql api
**Reactjs Code**

```
const RequestActionEnum = {
NEW: 'New',
UPDATE: 'Update',
ARCHIVE: 'Archive'
}

LocalCodeMutation({
      variables: {
        data: {
          id: null,
          city: values.jurisdiction,
          country: values.country,
          description: values.description,
          edition: values.edition,
          name: values.codeName,
          note: 'test',
          requestType: RequestActionEnum.NEW, // this is where i am sending enum value to api 
          state: values.state
        }
      }
    });
```

Below code is where I am calling the mutation

```
 const [LocalCodeMutation] = useMutation(LOCALCODE_MUTATION, {
refetchQueries: () => [
  { query: GET_LOCALCODES },
],
});

export const LOCALCODE_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation LocalCodeMutation($data:  LocalCodeRequestParamsInput) {
localCodeMutation(data: $data) {
  ok
  errors
  localCodeInsertedId
  }
 }
`;
```

I am getting this error when I send to the API:

> Error: GraphQL error: Variable $data got invalid value.

How can I send enum value to graphQL api from react component.

Could any one please suggest any ideas on this?

Comment: Why downvote on this question ? Is there Anything wrong with this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enum values for `RequestActionEnum` are

- `NEW`
- `UPDATE`
- `ARCHIVE`

If you were using this enum as a literal (not a variable), you would write it like this:

```
{
  someField(someArgument: NEW)
}
```

Similarly, if you're using variables, you would use `"NEW"`. Instead, you're using `"New"`, which is not a valid enum value for this particular enum.

FWIW, if you actually read through to the end of the error, it would tell you as much as well.

Comment: Thanks for the support , I need to send “New” to the api in that case what I need to do could you please guide me .thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to some other API you're calling from your GraphQL resolver?

Comment: i am calling .net core from this and using types with mutations inside it. Other than that nothing I am using

Comment: I need to compare the string  “New” inside api with the coming value from react app, could you please let me know how can I achieve this

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. The react app should be sending `NEW` instead of `New` since that's what's in your schema. You can change your schema so that the enum value is `New` instead if you like (they don't *have* to be all caps). Or you can just transform the value you receive inside your resolver. How that's done with a GraphQL.net needs to be a separate question. That has nothing to do with the error you're seeing.

Comment: even if i am did like this New: NEW i am getting same error, I am not sure where i am doing wrong here

Comment: It could also be an issue with another part of the object you're sending. Take a look at the complete error message you're getting back. Or update your question to include the full message.