# Can't send ENUM in variables GraphQL, Apollo

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I need to send array of object. In object some fields is Enum.
Like this:

```
user {
  first_name: string
  last_name: string
  title: enum
}
```

I'm sending array of users in variables like this:

```
$apollo.mutate({
  mutation: sendUsers,
  variables: users,
});
```

But my enums sending like string.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what errors are you getting? How is the schema typed? How is the resolver defined?

Comment: test mutation (with variables) in the playground before coding FE ... enum can be sent as a string

Comment: I'm tested this in playground and everthing work correct. How I can send enum not like string?

Comment: How to match/make sure enum in FE is equal to graphql enum and BE enum ... using string is a safe ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59187190/6124657